# How to describe a return object that provides a collection of functions with ngdocs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsdoc

I'm trying to create documentation based on the following structure:

```
/**
* @ngdoc service
*
* @name module:resource
* @module module
* @ return {Object} The returned object
*/

angular.module('module').factory('resource', [
  function () {
   function Foo (param1) {
      //Do something with param1
      }

      return {

         Test: {
           /**
            * @ngdoc function
            * @name resource#theTest
            * @methodOf module:resource
            *
            * @description
            * Search to see if a study exists with the given protocol identifier
            * @param  {Object} params The param
            * @return {Object}        A Promise
            */
          theTest: function(param) {
                return functionFoo (param);
           },

           /**
            * @ngdoc function
            * @name resource#theTest1
            * @methodOf module:resource
            *
            * @description
            * Search to see if a study exists with the given protocol identifier
            * @param  {Object} params The param
            * @return {Object}        A Promise
            */
           theTest1: function(param) {
               return functionFoo (param)
           }
        }
    };
   }
]);
```

What I would like to say in the documentation is that the service 'resource' returns an object that returns a collection of functions, but I cannot find the way of doing this with ngdocs. Is it supported?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could specify a 'map of function' the only type that are supported are Function, object, string, number, ...
But you could instead add a description in your class like:

````
/*
 * @description
 * This class return 2 functions as describe below:
 * ```js
 *  {
 *      theTest {Function} This function do (...)
 *      theTest1 {Function} This function do (...)
 *  };
 * ```
 */
function Foo (param1) {
````

Hope this will help